# AEM query to search on jcr:content properties only

Tags: full-text-search, aem, query-builder

We have a requirement to search on the jcr:content data only, we don't want to search results the component nodes.

Has anyone has any idea about this?

Thanks,
Mayur

Answer (score 0):

Even I had a similar issue, where I had to get data based on node name.

```
path=/content/geometrixx/en
nodename=jcr:content
```

In order to perform the search on a particular node. In the below example search key is 'available'.

```
path=/content/geometrixx/en
fulltext=available
fulltext.relPath=jcr:content
```

Reference: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/search/querybuilder-api.html

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: But we need to search a particular text on the jcr:content node, if we mention fulltext=something is searching all the nodes of the pages.

Comment: I have update pseudo in the above, to match your case. Mark as answer if this is what expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use JCR-SQL2 queries: `SELECT * FROM [cq:PageContent] WHERE NAME() = 'jcr:content'`

You can extend the query if you want to find only the nodes having a specific property; e.g: `jcr:content` nodes having the `jcr:title` property equal to *Bestseller*: `SELECT * FROM [cq:PageContent] AS node WHERE NAME() = 'jcr:content' AND CONTAINS(node.[jcr:title], 'Bestseller')`